# Oracle 10G copy schema using impdp, trigger owner and table owner are not the same

Tags: oracle, database-trigger, impdp

We have base schema HSE in oracle 10g XE database. For UAT and other purposes we create the duplicate of HSE in the same database with HSE_UAT (using expdp & impdp). All 60 triggers are imported without issues. But for 12 triggers OWNER is HSE_UAT but table owner is HSE. Then every time we are manually dropping the trigger in HSE and re-run the trigger in HSE_UAT with correct table owner.

Just curious to know why this is happening only for 12 triggers not for others...

Comment: Did you try to compare scripts & metadata for two triggers - one which imports OK, and another one which imports with issues? Any differences?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't try this before. Tomorrow morning I will check this and post you the differences if any.

Comment: The following trigger is having table owner issue when copying to new schema. 
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HSE.TRIG_UPD_LV
AFTER UPDATE ON  ESS_LEAVE_REQ  FOR EACH ROW
This one is copying without issues.
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "HSE"."TRG_ASSIGN_HOLIDAY" 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON HSE.TAS_HOLIDAYS FOR EACH ROW.

I am using toad and it is formatting the trigger metadata (removes the table owner name). Using dbms_metadata.get_ddl i found this issue now..  I will try to recreate the trigger with schemaname.table then will post you.

Comment: OK; I'm looking forward to see the outcome.

Comment: Yes now it is working. After dropping the trigger and recreated trigger without schema name( "HSE"."TRG_ASSIGN_HOLIDAY" to   "TRG_ASSIGN_HOLIDAY"). 
Now all the triggers are importing to new schema correctly.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! Thank you for the feedback.